# C++: Redirect code to certain position

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++.

How I can "redirect" code to certain position?

Basically, what should I put instead of comments lines here:

```
if ( N>1 ) {
  // What should be here to make the code start from the beginning? 
}
else {
  // What should be here to make the code start from certain point?
}
```

I understand that C++ is not scripting language, but in case the code is written as script, how I can make redirect it?

Thank you

Comment: Considered a loop already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `goto` command will do what you want but it's generally frowned on in polite circles :-)

It has its place but you would be possibly better off learning structured programming techniques since the *overuse* of `goto` tends to lead to what we call spaghetti code, hard to understand, follow and debug.

If your mandate is to make minimal changes to code which sounds like it may already be badly written, `goto` may be the best solution:

```
try_again:
n = try_something();
if (n > 1)
    goto try_again;
```

With structured programming, you would have something like:

```
n = try_something();
while (n > 1)
    n = try_something();
```

You may not see *much* of a difference between those two cases but that's because it's simple. If you end up with your labels and `goto` statements widely separated, or forty-two different labels, you'll beg for the structured version.

Comment: Thank you for this reply! Now I'm really concerned about the structure. I'm writing simple quadratic equation solver. I want the program to start over, after it has calculated roots (instead of quitting), then, after coefficients are defined by user, I want to give a chance to change them. What would be your structural suggestions in this case? And also, what can you suggest for  learning structured programming techniques? Thank you a lot!

Comment: @user40, ask another question, posting the actual code you have (this is important - without your code, we can onlyy give generalised answers) and asking how to do explicitly what you desire. The nature of StackOverflow is that questions are seen by almost everyone, comments tend to disappear into the background except for the Q/A that it's posted on. In other words, you'll get a much better response from a question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216431/c-basic-structured-programming-techniques

Answer (score 2):

Use functions, loops etc to control the "flow" of your application. Think about code as reusable pieces, anything that is going to be reused should be placed in a function or looped through.

Here is an example:

```
void main()
{
    int i = 0;

    SayHello();       

    if (i < 1)
    {
         SayHello();
         i++;
    }
    else
    {
         SayGoodbye();
    }
}

void SayHello()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}

void SayGoodbye()
{
    cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what you mean by "redirect", but consider the following:

```
if (N > 1) {
   speak();
} else {
   do_something_else();
}
```

as paxdiablo has already stated the `goto` method isn't good practice. It would be better to use functions that do a specific thing, this way debugging is easier and someone can actually follow what your code is doing (or at least what it is supposed to do).